# web scraping using selenium, how to get rid of multiple chromes popping up in menu bar

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple chrome apps opening in the menu bar. Has anyone experienced something similar or know how to stop that from happening?

[multiple chrome apps in menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd47M.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

*scraping*

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Could you please apparently explicit about what exactly the issue and in what scenario is these are on screen?